# PHP/MySQL Checking for null

Tags: php, mysql, null

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `phpbb_profile_fields_data`';

$result = $db->sql_query($sql);

while ($row = $db->sql_fetchrow($result)) {      
    if ($row['pf_kp_em_no_bonethr'] == '1') {
        echo " Was 1";
    } else if ($row['pf_kp_em_no_bonethr'] == '2') {
        echo "Was 2";
    } else {
        echo "Was Neither 1 or 2";
    }
}

$db->sql_freeresult($result);
```

I am curios, In my example I am checking the field for either a value of 1 or 2 but how do I check it for a value of NULL. Would it be any of the following three:

```
if ($row['pf_kp_em_no_bonethr'] == '')
if ($row['pf_kp_em_no_bonethr'] == '-1')
if ($row['pf_kp_em_no_bonethr'] == 'NULL')
```

Normally I would just try it out but I am not at home and wont be for the foreseeable future it has been bugging me. I am pretty sure it's not the second but I have seen -1 used for a null value in other languages. So can someone verify how I would indeed check for a NULL value please.

Comment: Have you tried it with the actual value `null` and not the string `'NULL'`?

Comment: pherhaps: `is_null($row['pf_kp_em_no_bonethr'])`

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql_fetch_* function does not return any NULL columns in the array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140515/mysql-fetch-function-does-not-return-any-null-columns-in-the-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work.

```
if (is_null($row['pf_kp_em_no_bonethr'])) {
  echo "Is NULL";
}
```

Comment: I did read about the is_null but could not fully understand how to implement it. thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 2):

```
if ($row['pf_kp_em_no_bonethr'] === NULL)
```

Comment: Was not aware of the === operator. What is it's purpose?

Answer (score 1):

MySQL will return NULL values to PHP as actual PHP `NULL`.  In this situation, what you need is:

```
// Notice lack of quotes around NULL
// And use === to distinguish type properly between integer 0 and NULL
if ($row['pf_kp_em_no_bonethr'] === NULL)
```

However, it would be more appropriate to check it in the query if NULL values are what you need to work with in PHP.

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `phpbb_profile_fields_data` WHERE pf_kp_em_no_bonethr IS NULL';
```

Or to find all three values:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `phpbb_profile_fields_data` 
 WHERE pf_kp_em_no_bonethr IS NULL
   OR pf_kp_em_no_bonethr IN (1,2)
';
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to be very carfull with this one: I have seen

```
<?php
$field=$row['fieldname'];
if ($field===null) {
  //Do something
}
?>
```

fail intermittently, especially on windows. This is why I prefer

```
SELECT
  IFNULL(fieldname,'some_safe_value') AS fieldname
  ...
FROM
...
```

and the resulting trivial null-check.

Comment: A few people seem to recommend the === NULL idea can this really cause issues?

Comment: I'd have recommended it also - were it not from bad experience. I have personally seen a DB-NULL field been given as an empty string, not a PHP-NULL on a Windows  installation. And before you ask: I triple-checked the query, and exact the same code against the physically same DB gave a PHP-NULL on anothe installation. Seems to be a property of the client version.

Answer (score 0):

Use [is_null](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.is-null.php) or === NULL.

```
if(is_null($row['pf_kp_em_no_bonethr'])){

}
```

or

```
if($row['pf_kp_em_no_bonethr'] === NULL){

}
```